# Am I required to file taxes on an LLC that made no money?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, limited-liability-company, new-york

I live in NY and created my LLC in November 2017. I didn't have any revenue for the two months of activity. Am I required to file taxes for 2017 on that LLC?

I can't imagine that they would want to process something that made $0.

I am the sole-proprietor of the LLC, no additional members and not treated as corporation.

Comment: You may not have made anything. But how do they know that if you don't file? They might not particularly want to process a null return but they have to process it to know it is a null return.

Comment: Did you file Form 8832 and elect to be taxed as a corporation? Are you the only member of your LLC?

Comment: See the full answer below. The LLC May never file a return.

Comment: "I can't imagine that they would want to process something that made $0." - I think you have too much faith in the logic of bureaucratic agencies.

Comment: If you’re running an LLC you need to acquire 2 absolutely critical services. A lawyer and an accountant. Get them on retainer so you can ask professionals these questions when they arise. Accountants make a living off knowing these things inside and out *for the location they work in*.

Comment: Even if you had no revenue, you probably had expenses...which means you lost money. That would reduce your taxable income, if you're filing schedule C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LLC doesn't really mean anything to the IRS. Your business filing requirements depend on how your LLC is treated for tax purposes. If you have a single-member LLC, then it's not considered a separate business entity by the IRS, you'd file a Schedule C like any sole-proprietor, and you only have a Schedule C filing obligation if your income is over $400 for the year (total from all businesses if you have multiple sole-proprietorships).

If you have partners in your LLC, then it's treated by the IRS like any other partnership, you only have to file a 1065 if you had any income or expenses for the year.

The caveat to both of the above is if you elected to have your LLC treated as a corporation then you must file a tax return for the corporation.

Here's a handy article from LegalZoom:

 [Do I Need to File a Tax Return for an LLC With No Activity?](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/do-i-need-to-file-a-tax-return-for-an-llc-with-no-activity)

 And this person asked a nearly identical question to yours over on the TurboTax foruum:

 [I started a LLC in 2016 that did not generate any income nor expenses. The LLC is still active is this something I need to add on my taxes?](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3755720-i-started-a-llc-in-2016-that-did-not-generate-any-income-nor-expenses-the-llc-is-still-active-is-this-something-i-need-to-add-on-my-taxes)

**Edit:** It occurred to me that NY may have its own requirement for filing. With no income to show, you do not have to file Form IT-204-LL  (LLC Filing Fee), so that saves you $25 (much higher annual fee if you elect to be treated as a corporation in the future, make sure to weigh that into your decision). I didn't see anything that suggested you'd have to file anything for your LLC in NY without income/losses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Even though you made no money you still have to file and say that you made no money.  I ran into this and never filed and I got hit with a $4000+ fine.  I was able to get out of the fine but still had to pay $160 for filing late.
I am from Ohio and im not sure if the rules are different but better be safe than sorry.